# vue-pdf unable load to all pages "undefined property"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I am using:

- Vue.js, vue-route, Vuetify, Firebase (database here) and vue-pdf

I am trying to load all pdf pages using **"vue-pdf"** but I get this error when I try to read the pdf.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'novel' of undefined

I have an object named **novel** which is set to null initially. When I get the data from Firebase, it gets assigned to this novel object. I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf#rotate-number---default-0) to load multiple pdf pages. However, in the tutorial a direct URL is used, but in my case I trying to access a specific value inside my object which is **"this.novel.nove_url"**. I'm not sure what I got wrong here, my code is below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <v-container fluid>
      <h1>{{novel.title}}</h1>
      <div class="novel-display container">
        <pdf
          v-for="i in numPages"
          :key="i"
          :src="src" //this should display the loaded pdf file
          :page="i"
          style="display: inline-block; width: 100%"
          @num-pages="pageCount = $event"
          @page-loaded="currentPage = $event"
        ></pdf>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-pagination v-model="currentPage" :length="pageCount" :total-visible="7" circle></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-container>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import pdf from "vue-pdf";
import db from "../db";
// var loadPDF = pdf.createLoadingTask(
//   "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/wcrjf9qPTCKXV3hMXDwK"
// );
var loadingTask = pdf.createLoadingTask(this.novel.novel_url); //the file I would like to load

export default {
  name: "Read",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer,
    pdf,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      novel: null, // data from Firebase is saved here
      src: loadingTask ,
      currentPage: 0,
      pageCount: 0,
      numPages: undefined,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.src.promise.then((pdf) => {
      this.numPages = pdf.numPages;
    });
  },
  created() {
    let ref = db
      .collection("Novels")
      .where("novel_slug", "==", this.$route.params.novel_slug);
    ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.novel = doc.data();
        this.novel.id = doc.id;
      });
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `this` outside of `export default` (see [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/access-props-outside-of-export-default-but-inside-script-tags/11916)). In addition, the Firebase database fetch is asynchronous, so the `novel` property is only populated when the promise returned by `get()` is fulfilled (i.e. [in the callback functions passed to the `then()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then))

You can initialize `loadingTask` in the `created()` hook, in `get().then()`, as follows (untested):

```
import Footer from "./Footer";
import pdf from "vue-pdf";
import db from "../db";

export default {
  name: "Read",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer,
    pdf,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      novel: null, // data from Firebase is saved here
      src: null ,
      currentPage: 0,
      pageCount: 0,
      numPages: undefined,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.src.promise.then((pdf) => {
      this.numPages = pdf.numPages;
    });
  },
  created() {
    let ref = db
      .collection("Novels")
      .where("novel_slug", "==", this.$route.params.novel_slug);
    ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.novel = doc.data();
        this.novel.id = doc.id;
      });
      this.src = pdf.createLoadingTask(this.novel.novel_url); 
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. This did work, I just had to take the code in the mounted function and put it under your solution and it worked. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: I just did. Thank you